# How to add supporting line to each row in grid display

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm creating an element that displays an arbitrary set of icons like beads on a string. So far, I've gotten the arrangement of the icons down with a grid display as follows (icons replaced with squares for demonstration purposes):

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font: .9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica,  sans-serif;
}

.container > div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(36,33,33);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30px, auto));
  gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
}
```

```html
    <h1>Simple grid example</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

But I have no idea how I would create a line on each row for the icons to sit on. See reference image:

[image: Beads]

Grey lines should be behind the black squares. Ideas:

1. Dynamically add divs to `container` that look like lines and then set their `grid-row` and `grid-col` properties to overlap with the blocks.
2. Instead of just having black squares as the elements of `container`, have a div that contains a black square and a horizontal line segment, so that each black square comes with a small piece of line. Then detect the edge squares of each row and either move the line, or half its width so that it doesn't show on the edges.

Both of these solutions seem quite involved, so before I go down the rabbit hole I wanted to ask if there was an easier way, even something not requiring JS.

Comment: Is it clear how many squares there will be on one line? Or the container is responsive?

Comment: @Azu, responsive

Comment: I can't see a solution without Javascript. It's a very interesting case. I suggest you to use three types of backgrounds and to calculate how many squares you have per line. Then the first one and the last one will have different backgrounds. I would use flex, not grid.

Comment: Is the width of each square fixed?

Comment: Yes the width and height are fixed and equal for all squares

Answer (score 2):

I think to use `pseudo-elements` will be better idea, because no need to add extra elements to the DOM.

1. Create a `pseudo-element` with the required properties  for all cells.
2. To shift `pseudo-element` to the left.
3. Add finally add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.container`  for hidden
   unnecessary `pseudo-elements`.

```css
.container div::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(var(--cell) + var(--column-gap)); /* 30px + 20px */
  height: var(--line-height); /* 3px */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --cell: 30px;
  --column-gap: 20px;
  --line-height: 3px;
}

body {
  width: 90%;
  /* max-width: 300px; */
  margin: 2em auto;
  font: 0.9em/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--cell), auto));
  gap: var(--column-gap);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(var(--cell), auto);
  overflow: hidden;  /* hide left side */
}

.container>div {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(36, 33, 33);
}

.container div::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(var(--cell) + var(--column-gap)); /* 30px + 20px */
  height: var(--line-height); /* 3px */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -50%;
  background-color: gray;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple grid example</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is a very cool solution, and I upvoted for that, but unfortunately it doesn't handle the responsive case. Note that the `grid-template-columns` is set to auto fill, so there may be less than 6 columns

Comment: Unfortunately it's not responsive.

Comment: I have update the snippet. Removed unnecessary, now the grid is *flexible*.

Comment: @jeanluc, As it's a very interesting task, I have tried to solve it but couldn't. So I have re-posted it and I've got a JS solution as well as a non-JS one. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418133/an-interesting-javascript-task/69423929#69423929

Answer (score 0):

Adaptation of the idea I provided for [@Azu's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418133), this time having the line run continuously from the center of the first square on the row to the center of last square of the row. Note, however, that this doesn't use grid layout.

```css
.container>div {
  display:inline;
}
.container > div .icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.bg::before {
  content: ' ';
  letter-spacing:70px;
  margin-right:-50px;
  position:relative;
  left: -25px;
  font-size:23px;
  border-bottom:2px solid lightgrey;
  vertical-align:top;
}

/* Just for demonstrating the responsiveness */
.container {
  border:1px solid;
  animation: 10s linear 1s infinite alternate setWidth;
}
@keyframes setWidth { from { width: 100%; } to { width: 50%; }  }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```