# An interesting Javascript task

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Azu777/rpgj3md7/2/)

There has been a similar task recently and I tried to solve it by Javascript but couldn't. So I need your help.

The idea is this: it's like beads on a lace but the left and the right beads have blue lines only on one side. Also the last square. The structure should be responsive, that's why I have used flex.

The blue lines are spans with a background color, but could be also borders if you like. By the Javascript I move them to the left when I need to hide them. If you put a border to those divs `.container > div`, you'll get my idea.

I thought my Javacsript should work but actually it works only partly. Where am I wrong? Thank you.

```js
const moveBackgrounds = () => {
    
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');

    const getY = (elem) => {
        const elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return elemRect.top + window.scrollY;
    }
    
    let countPerLine = 0; //count of divs per line
    let firstDivY = getY(divs[0]);
    
    divs.forEach(div => {
        if (getY(div) === firstDivY ) {
            countPerLine++  
        }
    });

    //positioning the blue divs:
    divs.forEach((div, index) => {
        
        if ((index+1) % countPerLine !== 0) {
            const spanBg = div.querySelector('.bg');
            spanBg.style.left = 0 + 'px';
            
        }
        else {
            const spanBg = div.querySelector('.bg');
            const left = spanBg.style.left;
            spanBg.style.left = left - 20 + 'px';
        }
    });
    
    
    
    //move the background of the last div:
    const spanBg = divs[divs.length - 1].querySelector('.bg');
    
    console.log(spanBg);
    const left = spanBg.style.left;
    spanBg.style.left = left - 20 + 'px';
        
    
}

window.addEventListener("resize", moveBackgrounds);
window.addEventListener("load", moveBackgrounds);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align:center
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;

}
.container > div {
  width: 70px;
  height:70px;
  position:relative
}
.container > div .icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translate(0,-50%);
    z-index:2
}



.container .bg{
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height:2px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 50%;
    left:0;
    transform:translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does seem like a fun challenge indeed.
Could you make a JSFiddle out of this so people can play around with the code to help you out?

Comment: JSFiddle added.

Comment: What seems to go wrong with your attempt?

Comment: The problem is that to the right side the blue lines don't hide. Also of the last item.

Comment: Does this have to involve Javascrit? It looks like a grid with media queries. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: At first it looks like CSS would be enough. However it's responsive and it's unknown how many squares will be on one row. To me that task looked very easy but when I tried it, it happened that it's not so simple. I wrote some code that I thought should work. However I have no idea why it doesn't. I'd like to know what the problem is.

Comment: This can be done entirely in CSS, no JS, responsively, without media queries and without changing your HTML. If you're interested, I'll post such a solution.

Comment: @Alohci, Yes please, I'm curios to see a solution without JS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you will get what you want by using:

`spanBg.style.display = 'none'`

for the last element in the divs list.

If I'm wrong, let me know.

Image added so you can see the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the calculation of the moving of a blue line element.

Notice that on first load the layout looks fine - the right hand blue line is not there - but on a resize of the window they come back.

Here's what's happening. This line

```
const left = spanBg.style.left;
```

picks up the style, which at the start is empty as it hasn't been set. However, once it has been set (either to 0px or -20px) then that's the string that is returned. Notice it is not a number, it has px at the end. Then you try to take away 20 and add a px string. This isn't recognised so the style.left stays as it was - either 0px or 20px.

This snippet sets the blue lines to display: none if they are on the end rather than trying to hide them by moving them. It also has to then set them back to display: block when they are not to be removed (just in case they'd been set to none the last time).

```js
const moveBackgrounds = () => {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');

  const getY = (elem) => {
    const elemRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return elemRect.top + window.scrollY;
  }

  let countPerLine = 0; //count of divs per line
  let firstDivY = getY(divs[0]);

  divs.forEach(div => {
    if (getY(div) === firstDivY) {
      countPerLine++
    }
  });

  //positioning the blue divs:
  divs.forEach((div, index) => {

    if ((index + 1) % countPerLine !== 0) {
      const spanBg = div.querySelector('.bg');
      spanBg.style.display = 'block';

    } else {
      const spanBg = div.querySelector('.bg');
      spanBg.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });



  //move the background of the last div:
  const spanBg = divs[divs.length - 1].querySelector('.bg');

  //console.log(spanBg);
  const left = spanBg.style.left;
  //spanBg.style.left = left - 20 + 'px';
  spanBg.style.display = 'none';

}

window.addEventListener("resize", moveBackgrounds);
window.addEventListener("load", moveBackgrounds);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container>div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative
}

.container>div .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  z-index: 2
}

.container .bg {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
    <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me and for telling me where I was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

This effect can be achieved entirely in CSS. To do so, the blue lines are created as the border or background of a space character, and makes use of the fact that spaces at the end of lines are dropped.

```css
.container > div {
  display: inline;
}
.container > div .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.container .bg::before {
  content: ' ';
  letter-spacing: 20px; /* adjust this to control the blue line length */
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/* Just for demonstrating the responsiveness */
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: 10s linear 1s infinite alternate setWidth;
}
@keyframes setWidth { from { width: 100%; } to { width: 30%; }  }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
        <div><span class="icon"></span><span class="bg"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a very good approach. Thank you.

Comment: Similar task here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397168/how-to-add-supporting-line-to-each-row-in-grid-display?noredirect=1#comment122675519_69397168